# Can't show that equations are the same

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

This is the problem i cant solve:

**Show that:**

$$
\frac {\tan^2(x-1)}{(\sin x+\cos x)} = \frac {(\sin x-\cos x)}{\cos^2x}
$$

I can't get any longer than:

Left-hand side:

$$
\frac{ {\sin^2(x-1) \over \cos^2(x-1) } *(\sin x-\cos x)} {\sin^2x-\cos^2x}
$$

Comment: Does it *really* say $\tan^2(x-1)$? That doesn't make sense. In fact, for $x=1$ the left hand side is zero while the right hand side is nonzero.

Comment: Hint: try "solving" the resulting equation to prove it holds for all x. Begin by multiplying by both the denominators.

Comment: $tan^2x-1$ it says

but i interpreted it as $tan^2(x-1)$

otherwise shouldn't stand $tan^2(x)-1$???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it was meant to be $\tan^2(x) -1$ because as it stands the statement is false. Notice using $\tan^2(x)-1$ then trying cross multiplication
$$
\begin{align}
 \tan^2(x)-1&=\frac{(\sin x-\cos x)(\sin x+\cos x)}{\cos^2 x}\\
 \tan^2(x)-1&=\frac{\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x}\\
\tan^2(x)=1&=\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}-\frac{\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}\\
\tan^2(x)-1&=\tan^2 x-1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Holy sh*t! Now it looks so easy. I spent hours on this problem -_-
Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

As written, it is not true, as can be immediately seen by letting $x=1.$ It is likely that it is instead supposed to be $$\frac{\tan^2x-1}{\sin x+\cos x}=\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\cos^2 x},$$ instead. To see why this holds, note that $$\tan^2x-1=\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)^2-1=\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2x}-1=\frac{\sin^2x-\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}.$$ See if you can take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac {\sin x-\cos x}{\cos^2x}=\frac {(\sin x-\cos x)(\sin x+\cos x)}{(\sin x+\cos x)\cos^2x}$$
$$=\frac {\sin^2x-\cos^2x}{(\sin x+\cos x)\cos^2x}=\frac{\tan^2x-1}{\sin x+\cos x}$$